# EventBus does not register event on new activity

Tags: android, otto, greenrobot-eventbus

I have implemented an otto bus example.  It works fine, but ONLY on the second time I visit the activity.

For example, when I load the app and hit the secret message button I am taken to the activity but the toast does not show. Then I hit the back button to return to the MainActivity and hit the show secret message button again and when I am taken to the secret message activity the toast is displayed.  I realize it works the second time because I have created a leak by not unregistering the event.

Is there something I am missing about the logic?

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button buttonSecretMessage;
    Intent intentToMessage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        intentToMessage = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecretMessageActivity.class);

        buttonSecretMessage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSecretMessage);

        buttonSecretMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                EventBus.getInstance().post(new MakeMySecretMessageEvent());
                startActivity(intentToMessage);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Secret Message Activity:

```
public class SecretMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_secret_message);

    }

    @Subscribe
    public void getMySecretMessage(MakeMySecretMessageEvent event){

        Toast.makeText(this, event.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();

        EventBus.getInstance().register(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        //EventBus.getInstance().unregister(this);

    }
}
```

MakeMySecretMessageEvent:

```
public class MakeMySecretMessageEvent {

    public MakeMySecretMessageEvent() {

    }

    public String getMessage() {

        String message = "YOU ARE AWESOME!";

        return message;
    }

}
```

EventBus:

```
public final class EventBus extends Bus{
    private static final EventBus Bus = new EventBus();

    public static Bus getInstance() {
        return Bus;
    }

    private EventBus() {
    }

}
```

Comment: Since your SecretMessageActivity does not exist, when your Event is fired, it can not receive the event. The 2 time it is working, because your SecretMessageActivity-instance is still in the memory. I guess you create a leak, because you do not unregister from the EventBus.

Comment: Thanks... That is why the unregister part is commented out.  So my question is, how do I get it to fire the first time?

Comment: What is your use case? Maybe you can set a extra to your Intent, which starts your SecretMessageActivity? See also the answer from UMESH0492.

Answer (score 1):

You can send sticky event using EventBus library. It allows you to send events to component which is not created yet.

You`ll find more info [here](http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/11/28/android-how-to-use-the-greenrobot-eventbus/).

Comment: Good to know!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here EventBus has applied in wrong scenario, when you can simply send data via intent or bundle. Which is more reliable in communication with one activity with another. You will never ever receive event on first click, as event fire is instant and your activity creation will take some time accordingly.

So try to use bundle or intent to setup communication b/w to activity one after another.

Comment: In this simple example I agree a bundle would be a much simpler solution, however, I am simply trying to figure out how to send object information from one activity to another using an event bus.

Comment: as i said above, you won't be able to. As before the second activity creates the event has been fired in first activity and no one is receiving that event @hpCode on first time, as no event registration has happened. And you are receiving it because you didn't unregister from the event (which would cause a leak) and when to call that activity again and it's having default launch mode. The instance of previous activity would call, which is already register with the event.

Comment: Got it :)....  So I need to create the second activity BEFORE I fire the event so that it can receive it?   Not sure how to do that...

Comment: Yeh, but how will you do that. You can't do that. As there is no concept of constructor when you create/initiate an activity .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to contributors I now have a better understanding of the activity life cycle and how it fits in with event bus.  That is you cannot send an event from the MainActivity to its children, but the other way around instead.  Below reflects how to implement an otto event bus to pass a simple object from an activity back to the main activity.  Hopefully someone else can find this useful :) And if this can be improved upon please comment. Thanks.

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button buttonSecretMessage;
    Intent intentToMessage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EventBus.getInstance().register(this);

        intentToMessage = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecretMessageActivity.class);

        buttonSecretMessage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSecretMessage);

        buttonSecretMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startActivity(intentToMessage);

            }
        });
    }
    public MakeMySecretMessageEvent event;
    @Subscribe
    public void getMySecretMessage(MakeMySecretMessageEvent event) {

            Toast.makeText(this, event.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if(event != null ){

            EventBus.getInstance().unregister(this);
        }
    }
}
```

SecretMessageActivity (this is where the secret message is created)

```
public class SecretMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button buttonClickToMeToSeeMessage;
    Intent intentToMain;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_secret_message);

        intentToMain = new Intent(SecretMessageActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

        buttonClickToMeToSeeMessage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClickToMeToSeeMessage);

        buttonClickToMeToSeeMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                MakeMySecretMessageEvent makeMySecretMessageEvent = new MakeMySecretMessageEvent();

                EventBus.getInstance().post(makeMySecretMessageEvent);

                startActivity(intentToMain);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

MakeMySecretMessageEvent

```
public class MakeMySecretMessageEvent {

    public MakeMySecretMessageEvent() {

    }

    public String getMessage() {

        String message = "YOU ARE AWESOME!";

        return message;
    }

}
```

EventBus:

```
public final class EventBus extends Bus{
    private static final EventBus Bus = new EventBus();

    public static Bus getInstance() {
        return Bus;
    }

    private EventBus() {
    }

}
```